# Pull latest workbook copy selected workbook and paste in master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to look in a folder to pull the latest workbook by date, open the workbook up as my src data, copy the selected worksheet and data from src and then paste to my master workbook. Finally closing the src workbook without saving any change. I'm having issues on where I should place my file paths and filenames.

```
Function NewestFileName(ByVal path As String, ByVal FileTemplate As String) As String

Dim FileDateCrnt As Date
Dim FileDateNewest As Date
Dim FileNameCrnt As String
Dim FileNameNewest As String

If Right("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST", 1) <> "\" Then
path = "G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST" & "\"
End If

FileNameCrnt = Dir$("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST" & Book1.xlsx)
If FileNameCrnt = "Book1.xlsx" Then
NewestFileName = "Book2.xlsx"
Exit Function
End If

FileNameNewest = FileNameCrnt
FileDateNewest = FileDateTime("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST" & FileNameCrnt)
Do While True
FileNameCrnt = Dir$
If FileNameCrnt = "" Then Exit Do
FileDateCrnt = FileDateTime(path & FileNameCrnt)
If FileDateCrnt > FileDateNewest Then
  FileNameNewest = FileNameCrnt
  FileDateNewest = FileDateCrnt
End If
Loop

NewestFileName = FileNameNewest

Call ReadDataFromCloseFile

End Function

Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim src As Workbook

Set src = Workbook.Open("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST.xlsx", True, True)

Dim iTotalRows As Integer
iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

Dim iCnt As Integer
For iCnt = 1 To iTotalRows
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & iCnt).Formula
Next iCnt

src.Close False
Set scr = Nothing

ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "Much grass" ?!? I think you mean "many thanks". As in "muchas gracias". lol

Answer (score 2):

First things first:

If you have a question or encounter an error, then spell it out. It's hard to find out where your error is, without knowing on which line it occurs.

Your function in a whole doesn't make that much sense. For taking a good look at it, commenting would've been very helpful.

Let's go through your code step by step:

```
If Right("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST", 1) <> "\" Then
path = "G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST" & "\"
End If
```

This if-condition will always trigger, because the String you put in there, is always the same and it'll always miss the "\". 
So if your path doesn't change then you can change that to `path = "G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST\"`

---

```
FileNameCrnt = Dir$("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST" & Book1.xlsx)
If FileNameCrnt = "Book1.xlsx" Then
NewestFileName = "Book2.xlsx"
Exit Function
End If
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. You are setting `FileNameCrnt` to a string in the first line (you are missing the "\" btw). I guess "Book1.xlsx" is the real name of your workbook, so your String should look either like this: `"G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST\Book1.xlsx"` or you could do something like this

```
fileName = "Book1.xlsx"
FileNameCrnt = Dir$("G:\AOC\GROUPS1\SAC\TEST" & fileName )
```

Next: You would(!) always exit the function there, if the line above would work. You set FilenameCrnt to Book1.xlsx, then check it via an if-clause, the check will always return `true`, afterwards you'd always exit.

---

I get the idea of your loop, but it too is broken. Start by changing this: `If FileNameCrnt = "" Then Exit Do` to something else. Your variable will never be empty so your loop will always cause a runtime error. Start changing the first parts of your function and get to that later. I think you will have a better idea how all this should work. And it's always better to try solving some things by yourself. ;)

EDIT:

It's always helpful to make a flow chart on how your program should run.
Something like:

- **Get** my current filename
- **Get** date of my current file
- **Check if** there is a newer file (a file with a higher date than my old
  date)
- **Get** dates of **all** files (loop through all files)
- **GET** highest date
- **Compare** highest date to date of my current file
- **if** there is a file with a higher date, **update** current filename to filename with higher date

HTH

Comment: Ok so everything is all messed up... haha so much for me piecing things together lol

Comment: @Marro24 - I don't think **everything is all messed up**. The biggest problem I see in understanding your issue is that you don't even use the arguments passed into your function (I suspect you hard-coded the variables when testing and posted the code this way). If you can edit your post with the function using the arguments passed and the tell us the exact place where the error occurs we can help you a lot more effectively.

Comment: Well I saw this code that someone had posted that seemed to fit my issues exactly and tried to copy that and insert what was directly my path and files but I think I just messed up their code.... I will post under mine that original code I copied before touching it.

Comment: @Marro24, I think that this code could look alot smaller. It does seem all over the place. ONe thing I think might need to be included with the copy paste logic is to include an offset into the master workbook (unless you dont mind losing data).

Comment: I think I'm going to try to rewrite some things and see what happens I know its a mess thanks guys